# Remove Text between HTML Tags in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a requirement to remove the entire HTML Text present in the code.
For example,
For the below text:

```
Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test</a> Inside Tags </div>
```

Expected output is:

```
Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2
```

I tried the below code but it is only removing the HTML Tags and not the text between them. Please note the HTML text can be anything like tag inside tag inside tag.:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test</a> Inside Tags </div>', '<.+?>') from dual
```

Comment: Your approach is incorrect (in general) regardless of anything else. You are not looking to match tags - you are simply looking for the characters `<` and `>` which may appear in many other contexts in your string values, unrelated to HTML tags. If in fact they can't, that's additional information you didn't share with us in your question.

Comment: Is there any way I can remove all the text within HTML Tags including the HTML Tags in SQL?

Comment: Note, that `some text <br> some text <br> another text` is also valid, but there's no nested structures here.

Comment: Simple remove the non-greedy quantifier from `'<.+?>'` making it to `'<.+>'` and it start working. Anyway you'll get a far better *performance* (for large data) using the `instr`/ `substr` approach.

Answer (score 0):

If HTML part is always going to be at the last of string, then you can use below query -

```
SELECT SUBSTR ('Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test</a> Inside Tags </div>'
               ,1
               , INSTR('Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test</a> Inside Tags </div>', '<') - 1
              )
from dual
```

Comment: html part is not going to be the last part always

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a *substring* between the first occurence of `<` and the last occurence of `>` (I'm deliberately *not* speaking about `HTML`)

than `instr` is your friend.

Simple find the position of the substrings:

first occurence of `<`

```
   instr(text,'<')-1 first_pos,
```

last occurence of `>`

```
   instr(text,'>',-1,1)+1 last_pos
```

and use `substr`to remove the not wanted part. I added in the query some handling for inconsistences (that *could appear in your string* if you for example combine the HTML with a formula `2 > 1` - see examples below) feel free to adapt them to your requirements

Query with sample data

```
with tab as 
(select 'Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test</a> Inside Tags </div>' text from dual union all
 select 'Notes without Text' from dual union all
 select 'Notes < inconsistent' from dual union all
 select 'Notes2 > inconsistent2' from dual),
tab2 as (
select text,
       instr(text,'<')-1 first_pos,
       instr(text,'>',-1,1)+1 last_pos
from tab)
select text, 
       substr(text,1,first_pos) || case when (first_pos = -1 and last_pos = 1) then substr(text,last_pos) end new_txt
from tab2 

TEXT                                                                          NEW_TXT                                                                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------
Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test</a> Inside Tags </div> Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2                                                                                                                  
Notes without Text                                                            Notes without Text                                                                                                                                        
Notes < inconsistent                                                          Notes                                                                                                                                                     
Notes2 > inconsistent2
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do your job. It covers two more cases :

- Case where html part is not the last part
- Case where you would have nested html (eg nested html )

```sql
with t (col) as (
SELECT 'Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test </a> Inside Tags </div>' from dual union all
SELECT 'Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> <a> test </a> Inside Tags </div> html part is not going to be the last part always' from dual union all
SELECT 'Notes Test with Text between Tags Part 2<div> whatever xxx <div> whatever yyy </div> <a> test </a> Inside Tags </div> html part is not going to be the last part always' from dual
)
select 
    col
  , substr(col, 1, left_part_end#) 
      || substr(col
          , instr(col, '</'||match_balise||'>'
          , -1
          , 1) + length(match_balise) + 3 
                /* why 3 ? ==> 3 = length('</>') */
        ) html_removed_col
from (
  select col
      , regexp_instr(col, '^(.*?)(<(.+?)>).+?(</\3>)(.*?)$', 1, 1, 0, '', 2 ) - 1 left_part_end#
      , substr (col
          , regexp_instr(col, '^(.*?)(<(.+?)>).+?(</\3>)(.*?)$', 1, 1, 0, '', 3 )
          , regexp_instr(col, '^(.*?)(<(.+?)>).+?(</\3>)(.*?)$', 1, 1, 1, '', 3 ) 
              - regexp_instr(col, '^(.*?)(<(.+?)>).+?(</\3>)(.*?)$', 1, 1, 0, '', 2 ) - 1
        ) match_balise
  from t
)
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78acf68370c20583e6b61f17b41c06d6)